# Unable to edit integration

Tags: module, error, custom, magento-community, magento2.4.2

We recently cleaned up our Magento 2.4.2 store so we had no generic users. Since we did this we noticed one of our integrations shows as inactive and we are unable to Activate or edit the integration, getting the following error: Internal error. Check exception log for details.

**Checking the log file i can see the following error:**

> [2021-06-15 07:45:20] main.CRITICAL: The role wasn't found for the user. Verify the role and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthorizationException(code: 0): The role wasn't found for the user. Verify the role and try again.

**Really hoping for some advise on this**

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Getting this error in 2.4.3-p1, when trying to authorize/activate a integration

Comment: For us we had a record of our API users and after the clean up we realised the user was deleted. Recreating the user resolved our issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check ACL file suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811151/magento-2-setup-upgrade-error-we-cant-find-the-role-for-the-user-you-wanted
Just debug there, you will find it which role it is looking or is there any other issue